# angular 2 AOT - with Third Party Libraries

Tags: angular, aot

I am using Highcharts and Kendo Charts in my angular 2 app, When I try to run through AOT compilation, it throws Errors like

```
Cannot Import Module
```

or

```
HomeModule' is not exported by
```

or

```
Cannot Determine Module ..
```

I came to know that I should import ***.metadata.json*** file for all the third party files.

How to create them? or where to find them? or If no such file is present for any third party library what to do?

Answer (score 3):

[Per @angular issue comment:](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11262#issuecomment-244472000)

> All referenced, 3rd party libraries must include the .metadata.json
>   file   along side any .d.ts files they produce otherwise they will not
>   work   correctly with ngc. The .metadata.json file contains the
>   information we need   that was in the original .ts file but was not
>   included in the .d.ts file. If   we don't have that information we
>   cannot generate the factories for the   library.
>
> The .metadata.json files are produced automatically by ngc. They
>   should be   built and delivered by the library vendor and require the
>   .ts files.

If the 3rd party dependency you want to use doesn't ship with `metadata.json` files, you can try building it with `ngc` yourself, but doing so may *not* be simple. `ngc` may fail with errors when `tsc` doesn't, perhaps because the code is not [statically analyzable](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5#.a68ln8ljb).

Comment: That statement is correct as it relates to TS files.  However, a lot of 3rd party libraries are built as regular JS files, and they work just by including the script.

Comment: Kendo Charts and Highcharts are regular JS libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Kendo charts and Highcharts are regular JS libraries - not a TypeScript library that's compiled to JavaScript - metadata.json files are not applicable here.

The libraries should work as is (I've run a test and confirmed that it works).  I believe the issue that you're having is likely related to your build.

For most JS libraries, you need to either install the Type Definition file (.d.ts) if they are available:

```
npm install @types/highcharts
```

If they don't exist (or the version is incorrect) then you can declare the variable as `any` instead:

```
declare var Highcharts:any;
```

### Demonstration (the Proof)

If you want to do a simple test to show that it works, download the following reference application:

https://github.com/pixelbits-mk/ng2-starter-app

### Create the re-usable module with Highcharts

### Step 1

Unzip the reference application to a folder called "features" (that will be the name of the module).

### Step 2

Install the Highcharts package.

```
npm install highcharts --save
```

### Step 3

Name your module `features` and give it an initial version number: 1.0.0

**package.json**

```
name: 'features',
version: '1.0.0'
```

### Step 4

Create the re-usable component that will contain the chart. Let's keep it simple.

**chart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Highcharts: any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'chart',
    templateUrl: 'chart.component.html'
})
export class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure you render the DIV for the chart container.

**chart.component.html**

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;">
    test
</div>
```

### Step 5

Export the ChartComponent from the module.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChartComponent } from './chart.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule        
    ],
    exports: [ChartComponent],
    declarations: [ChartComponent],
    providers: [/* TODO: Providers go here */],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Step 6a (optional)

If you want to test out the component at this stage, include the `<chart>` tag in `app.component.html` and build it in DEV and PROD (aot) mode.

```
npm run dev
npm run app
```

### Step 6b

Build and deploy the `features` module.  This creates the UMD, CJS, and AMD modules in the `dist` folder if you plan to use JIT and a module loader, or builds the necessary JS and .metadata files in the `dist\src` folder if you plan to use AOT without a module loader.

```
gulp module
```

The `features` module can now be published to `npm`:

```
npm publish
```

Or you can leave it in shared folder where others can access and install it.

### Creating the App that will install the Features Module

### Step 1

Download the another copy of the reference application into a folder called 'App'. This application will install the `features` module you created previously.

### Step 2

Install the `features` module from `npm`

```
npm install 'features'
```

Or install the `features` module from a shared folder

```
npm install '../features';
```

### Step 3

Import the `features` module

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppModule as FeatureModule } from 'features';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FeatureModule      
        ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [/* TODO: Providers go here */],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### Step 4

Add the chart tag to `app.component.html`

**app.component.html**

```
<chart></chart>
```

### Step 5

Run the app using the AOT build

```
npm run app
```

### Step 6

Voila!

[image]